# What does "Strength modifier damage" mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, damage

Some powers, for instance the warden's Earth Shield Strike, say "1[W] plus Strength modifier damage", though I've seen the same line used with different ability scores in different powers.

What is this "modifier damage"? I think it is your strength score, cut in half?

Comment: Which power? Not every power adds the modifier, and most add the whole one. If you're asking *how to calculate the modifier, then this question has the answers: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37175/1084

Comment: We need loads more information here. Where are you reading "damage modifier"? What kind of damage modifier are you after?

Comment: My guess is this answer is asking for both how to calculate the (for instance) Str modifier starting from the Str score, but also which other bonuses apply to the damage modifier to attacks (maybe the one in the 4e official character sheet). If it's not so, please tell us.
Also, you'll probably get some downvotes because it looks like there has been poor research on your part.

Comment: @Zachiel I downvoted because it's totally unclear what's being asked, not so much lack of research.

Comment: Warden attack, Earth Shield Strike. It says 1W plus Str modifier damage. Srry for lack of info

Comment: @user15854 take a look at the question I linked, it's got an answer for you.

Comment: I would reopen and then close as a duplicate.

Comment: I'd be happy to open this for answers and simply explain with a reference to that other question - since this question _doesn't exactly_ have an answer there.

Comment: This is a duplicate because it's not misunderstanding [w] or how to add it to the str mod, it just doesn't understand what a strength mod is, and that is covered by the linked question.

Comment: @mxyzplk It's not a duplicate. It's not misunderstanding what a strength *mod* is, it's not understanding what the non-existent "str mod *damage*" is, because they're misreading the words and it's a non-existent game object. (See my answer.)

Comment: I think you are seeing nuance that does not exist here at this way more basic level of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

An ability modifier (strength in this instance), is calculated by taking the strength score, subtracting 10 and dividing the remainder by 2 (round down).

So if your score is 18, your modifier is 4.

So in the power with a text of 1[W]+str, with a longsword, the damage at L1 with a Strenght of 18 would be:

```
 1d8+4 (plus other modifiers)
```

As your strength increases (to 20 and beyond), your modifier increases.

Answer (score 1):

“Strength modifier damage” doesn't mean anything, because it's two fragments of two different pieces of the phrase. This wording is really common in 4e powers, and makes straightforward sense… once you've seen how to read it, that is. It's a little bit like a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) though, so it's not really your fault for reading it wrong.

How you've parsed the phrase is

> ( **1[W]** ) plus ( **Strength modifier damage** )

The actual parsing is

> ( **1[W] plus Strength modifier** ) damage

So to find the damage the power deals, make one roll of your weapon's damage dice and add the value of your strength modifier.